# 404 not found error uploading file to box.com?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, box-api

I've been struggling to get the upload file post to work.  All I get is a 404 not found error which isn't helping.  I'm using C# HttpWebRequest.  When I catch the request in fiddler this is what it looks like.

--

```
  POST https://api.box.com/2.0/files/content HTTP/1.1
  Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=APK_KEY&auth_token=AUTH_TOKEN
  Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------8cfa73fa0212bf1
  Host: api.box.com
  Content-Length: 198082


  ------------------------------8cfa73fa0212bf1

  ------------------------------8cfa73fa0212bf1
  Content-Disposition: form-data; name="folder_id";

  532901558
  ------------------------------8cfa73fa0212bf1

  ------------------------------8cfa73fa0212bf1
  Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"; filename="Pasha.pdf"
  Content-Type: application/pdf

  %PDF-1.5
  %����
  1 0 obj
  <</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R/Lang(en-CA) /StructTreeRoot 29 0 R/MarkInfo<</Marked true>>>>
   endobj
  2 0 obj

  // rest of file data goes here ... too long to post

  ------------------------------8cfa73fa0212bf1
```

Comment: are you sure you have folder with 532901558 id on your box account?

Comment: I attempted to write to it and got a 403 (Forbidden) response, so presumably there is a folder on the other side.

Comment: @JohnHoerr you need to have APK_KEY and AUTH_TOKEN in order to upload files

Comment: I know -- I tried to write to that folder using *my* credentials.  I would have expected to receive a 404 if the folder didn't exist, but instead I got a 403, which suggests that the folder does exist (and I'm not allowed to write to it).

Comment: @user1902149 Could you try the write again with folder_id = '0'?  That's your root folder; it would rule out the folder existence issue.

Comment: You cant succeed to write to his folder with your credentials :)

Answer (score 0):

This is example of request what do you need to send to box.com

```
POST https://api.box.com/2.0/files/content HTTP/1.1
Authorization: BoxAuth api_key={key}&auth_token={token}
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="d174f29b-6def-47db-8519-3da38b21b398"
Host: api.box.com
Content-Length: 314
Expect: 100-continue

--d174f29b-6def-47db-8519-3da38b21b398
Content-Disposition: form-data; filename="hello.txt"; name="filename"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

{Bytes}
--d174f29b-6def-47db-8519-3da38b21b398
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="folder_id"

0 
--d174f29b-6def-47db-8519-3da38b21b398--
```